# A program that checks if the sum of the divisors are equal to the number doesn't work

Tags: c++

So I've tried to make a short program that would get an input n that would represent the number you want to put into it, then it checks if the sum of the divisors of this number is equal to it, then at the end it shows how many numbers that have the sum of the divisors equal to them, but for some reason, it doesn't work, it always shows 0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, k, l, i, j, m;

    cin >> n;
    m = 0;
    l = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> k;
        m = 0;

        for (j = 1; j <= n/2; j++) {
            if (k%j == 0) {
                m = m + j;
            }
        }
        if (k == m){
            l++;
        }
    }
    cout << l;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: you should provide more information. Add example input and expected output to your question. Details matter. If I run this code and do not enter something then nothing happens, no output on the screen, and thats completely fine and expected

Comment: So I've inputed 4 and then the numbers were 1 2 3 6, it should say output 1 since 6 is the only one that has it's sum of divisors equal to itself 1+2+3, but it outputed 0, I also tried 2 with the numbers 6 and 6, I thought that maybe for some strange reason it started from -1 and it would output 1 when it should output 2 but in reality, it was still 0 the output, so I don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: the code and your descprtion do not match. You say you are checking divisors of `n` but thats not what the code does. The code asks for `n` and then n-times for input `k` to calculate divisors of `k`.

Comment: `int n, k, l, i, j, m;` Don't do this to yourself. Give variables (and everything that you name) a descriptive name. No one but the you, and probably not even the future you, knows what those variables mean without having to read the code, a harder than necessary task because the purpose of the variables are obscured. This slows you down. It's also very easy to swap two letters in the code without realizing it or seeing it even after repeated attempts.

Comment: cannot reproduce. If I enter 4 1 2 3 6 the output is 1 as expected https://godbolt.org/z/hrYMerfMo

Comment: I thought that I would do this program just to familiarize myself with c++ as I'm pretty new to it

Comment: did you write the code? Frankly its odd that it works (somewhat) but you say it doesnt and that it does something else than what you describe, actually it does something more complicated that what you describe. In any case it does *not* output 0 always

Comment: @loltrox *but for some reason ...* -- When you write a program, you should know what every line, variable, function, etc. is *supposed* to do.  Once you see that your program is not working as expected, you should *debug* the program to see where the program diverges from the plan.  As a programmer, you cannot say "for some reason", that is unacceptable.  Fixing the error, yes, that could be difficult, and maybe impossible, but identifying where the error is, that is something you should be responsible for.

Answer (score 2):

Using more meaningful names exposes the bug immediately:

```
int main()
{
    int tests, number, successes, test, candidate, sum;

    cin >> tests;
    sum = 0;
    successes = 0;

    for (test = 0; test < tests; test++){
        cin >> number;
        sum = 0;

        for (candidate = 1; candidate <= tests/2; candidate++) {
            if (number%candidate == 0) {
                sum = sum + candidate;
            }
        }
        if (number == sum){
            successes++;
        }
    }
    cout << successes;

    return 0;
}
```

It is now obvious that you're using the wrong upper boundary in the innermost loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
  for (j = 1; j <= n/2; j++) {
```

`n` tells you how many numbers you want to check, but the number which you are actually checking is `k`, so it should be

```
  for (j = 1; j < k; j++) {
```

I also removed the division by 2, assuming you want to sum up all the divisors.

Comment: the code asks the user for how many numbers they want to enter (n). Then asks the user n-times for a number (k), eventually it prints the amount of entered numbers which equal the sum of their divisors. Its not what OP describes in their text, but it works as expected, it does not always output 0 as claimed by OP. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/hrYMerfMo

Comment: Well when I tested in codeblocks it didn't work so maybe it was a problem on my side.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The test works for this specific input of `4 1 2 3 6`. But, for example, for `1 6` it shows 0, while it should still print 1.